# wmv video; packet fragment position invalid; what does it mean and how to resolve it

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe, wmv

I am trying to do some work on a wmv video file. I'm using ffmpeg and ffprobe. I'm getting the message: "packet fragment position invalid 0,0 not in 0".

I am not familiar with video processing, quite a newbie actually. I didn't find an explanation what this exactly means and no hints on how to possibly resolve that problem.

I am able to play the video using VLC media player as well as other players.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your file with a small utility a wrote a long time ago. It's available here: http://radioactivepages.com/asfbin.aspx
Maybe you will discover what's wrong with the file. Or at least let me know what's the error if any.